# How to link / export existing Keycloak user to LDAP

Tags: jboss, ldap, keycloak, openldap, jboss-tools

I'm using Keycloak and just setup some OpenLDAP. Importing from LDAP to Keycloak works fine. Even new registrations and updates to users are synced nicely. But I can't find any way to:
*a) Export existing Keycloak users to LDAP

b) Linking existing Keycloak users to existing LDAP users*

when users already exist in Keycloak, during import I get the following error:

> 23:56:39,507 WARN 
>   [org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProviderFactory] (default
>   task-22) User 'foo' is not updated during sync as he already exists in
>   Keycloak database but is not linked to federation provider 'ldap'

Any Ideas? Did I missed something obvious?

Comment: IMHO Keycloak is not designated for this use case. Idea: use Keycloak admin API to dump all users and create missing users in LDAP manually with the custom script. Then LDAP will be in the good state for Keycloak.

Comment: Any new informations for this use case since the last 8 months?

Answer (score 0):

To send users to LDAP please try to use options "Edit mode: Writable" and "Sync Registrations: ON" on ldap configuration page in Keycloak (User Federation->Ldap).